# How to count the number of elements is empty in JSON?

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json data like this:

```
{
    "contract_no":"1",
    "history_no":"",
    "f_sin":"",
    "line_no":"",
    "p_typeid":"3",
    "compare_typeid":1,
    "val_typeid":"1",
    "goal_val":0,
    "count_typeid":1,
    "f_pb_ignore":0,
    "all_products":0,
    "judge_typeid":"",
    "reach_condition_array":[
        {
            "up_s_line_no":1,
            "t_from":111,
            "t_to":222,
            "rebate":11
        },
        {
            "up_s_line_no":2,
            "t_from":222,
            "t_to":null,
            "rebate":22
        }
    ],
    "series_appoint":[
        {
            "down_s_line_no":1,
            "deptCD":"0",
            "categoryCD":"12",
            "singleJan":"",
            "seriesJan":"",
            "fExclude":0
        },
{
            "down_s_line_no":1,
            "deptCD":null,
            "categoryCD":"4",
            "singleJan":"",
            "seriesJan":"",
            "fExclude":0
        },
{
            "down_s_line_no":1,
            "deptCD":"55",
            "categoryCD":"",
            "singleJan":"",
            "seriesJan":"",
            "fExclude":0
        },
{
            "down_s_line_no":1,
            "deptCD":"",
            "categoryCD":2222,
            "singleJan":"58796",
            "seriesJan":"1000000009",
            "fExclude":0
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to know in array "series_appoint",how many "deptCD" element is "" or null,and how many "singleJan" is "" or null.

In my example,the count of "deptCD" is "" or null is 2,the count of "singleJan" is "" or null is 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array#filter` to return the matching elements from the array, and then count the length.

```js
let obj = {"contract_no":"1","history_no":"","f_sin":"","line_no":"","p_typeid":"3","compare_typeid":1,"val_typeid":"1","goal_val":0,"count_typeid":1,"f_pb_ignore":0,"all_products":0,"judge_typeid":"","reach_condition_array":[{"up_s_line_no":1,"t_from":111,"t_to":222,"rebate":11},{"up_s_line_no":2,"t_from":222,"t_to":null,"rebate":22}],"series_appoint":[{"down_s_line_no":1,"deptCD":"0","categoryCD":"12","singleJan":"","seriesJan":"","fExclude":0},{"down_s_line_no":1,"deptCD":null,"categoryCD":"4","singleJan":"","seriesJan":"","fExclude":0},{"down_s_line_no":1,"deptCD":"55","categoryCD":"","singleJan":"","seriesJan":"","fExclude":0},{"down_s_line_no":1,"deptCD":"","categoryCD":2222,"singleJan":"58796","seriesJan":"1000000009","fExclude":0}]};

function blank(value) {
  return value === null || value.trim() === '';
}

let series = obj.series_appoint;
console.log('deptCD', series.filter(item => blank(item.deptCD)).length);
console.log('singleJan', series.filter(item => blank(item.singleJan)).length);
```

Comment: I use your code in my js,but the error said "Syntax error on token ">", delete this token",how do modify?

Comment: @Rhaegal -- please edit the question and include the exact code which you're running. Moreover, please post the entire error, with backtrace.